# How to install library into my maven's local repo in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am completely new to Maven. I am using eclipse 2021-12 and i am trying to follow the installation from [this link](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api) but do it in eclipse.

However, i am struggling to carry out the first step in eclipse "Install library into your Maven's local repository by running `mvn install`". I have created a new simple Maven Project and added the dependency code in step 2. And it gave me an error saying missing jar file.

My question is how do i carry out step 1 in eclipse ?

This is how the `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>binance.crypto</groupId>
  <artifactId>binance.crypto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.binance.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>binance-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The error i am getting is `missing artifact com.binance.api:binance-api-client:jar:1.0.0:`

**Solution:**

1. Clone the project from github and import as a normal project (not maven project) in eclipse
2. Right Click and run as `Maven Install`

Then it's completed

Comment: Note that these instructions are _completely nonstandard_ for Maven. Binance should have published this for you already, and all you should have to do is add the dependency in your POM.

Comment: yes i added the dependency code add in the POM but it's saying that jar is missing ...do i need to enable something in eclipse to ensure that it is pulling the jar files?

Comment: You need to clone the binance-api-client repo, and run `mvn install` in the root directory of the repo.